# How to apply line break after space using CSS?

Tags: css, word-break

I am populating some data using JSON and that is dynamic data, So what I want is to break if there is a space in between the word, I have tried all the CSS but it is not working

I don't know what is going wrong.

**I have tried these things**

- `.name_class { white-space: normal; }`
- `white-space: pre-line;`

[Working code](https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-haze-plz9v?file=/src/styles.css:29-35)

Comment: Try `.name_class { width: min-content }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one `min-content` will break word after space

```html
<div id="content" style="width: min-content;">aaaaaaaa bbbbbbbb</div>
```

Comment: hey I have one doubt regarding the answer u have posted, could you please clear it

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you:

```
.name_class {
  word-spacing: 9999px;
}
```